# Bluetooth keyboard with Mac layout and internal battery charged via USB-C

Tags: keyboards, bluetooth, apple, usb-c, macos

I want a wireless keyboard to use when my MacBook Pro 2018 is on a laptop stand.
Requirements:

- Same layout and size as MacBook Pro's keyboard (pic below). In particular, the `fn` key needs to be exactly in the lower left. About 30 centimeters wide, no numeric pad.
- Internal battery.
- Rechargeable by USB-C.
- Bluetooth.
- Compatible with current macOS.

Any price is fine. Either mechanical/chiclet/other is OK. No color/material/key-shape preferences as long as it is usable to type at normal/high speed.

Non-solutions:

- Apple's Magic Keyboard is not a solution because it uses a Lightning cable, rather than USB-C.
- Penclic KB3 is not a solution because its FN and CTRL keys are inverted.

QA:

- *Why not removable batteries? Because they are bothersome, and I work in places where batteries are not readily available.*
- *Why USB-C? Because USB-C is the only cable I use. I don't want another cable laying around just for this. All of my devices are Android so USB-C is enough to charge everything. Adapters are not a solution because they are unaesthetic and easily lost.*
- *Why Bluetooth? Because dongles are unaesthetic and easily lost.*

[image]

Comment: _"Why USB-C? Because USB-C is the only cable I use."_ Are you aware that you can buy a small USB-C to lightning adapter, to plug between your USB-C cable and the lightning input port of the Apple Magic Keyboard?

Comment: @mhucka: Thanks for you comment. I edited my question to detail that adapters are not a solution because they are unaesthetic and easily lost.