# Mac-compatible Bluetooth mouse with internal battery charged via USB-C

Tags: bluetooth, mice, apple, usb-c, macos

I want a wireless mouse to use with my MacBook Pro 2018.
Requirements:

- Internal battery.
- Rechargeable by USB-C.
- Usable while charging.
- Bluetooth.
- Compatible with current macOS.
- Fits large hand.
- Allows at least left-click, right-click, vertical scrolling.
- Real mouse, not a touchpad. Trackpoint would be wonderful if integrated in a keyboard that fits [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14341/bluetooth-keyboard-with-mac-layout-and-internal-battery-charged-via-usb-c).

Any price is fine.

Non-solutions:

- Apple's Magic Mouse is not a solution because it uses a Lightning cable, rather than USB-C.
- The AE WISH ANEWISH mouse is not a solution because it uses a micro-USB cable, rather than USB-C.

QA:

- *Why not removable batteries? Because they are bothersome, and I work in places where batteries are not readily available.*
- *Why USB-C? Because USB-C is the only cable I use. I don't want another cable laying around just for this. All of my devices are Android so USB-C is enough to charge everything.*
- *Why Bluetooth? Because dongles are unaesthetic and easily lost.*

Comment: With the low margins on mice and the extra 1-2$ in chips you need to use USB-C it will be a hard find. Although recently EU has decided to pass a law standarizing the (phone?) charging port as USB-C so you might have better luck sometime in H2 next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I recommend Logitech's MX Master 3.

[image]

- Internal battery, with USB-C (and fast charging!)
- Bluetooth and USB dongle support
- Cross-platform support; Bluetooth works on all systems with support for Bluetooth mice. Optional configuration software is supported on macOS and Windows.
- Medium-large
- 7 buttons, vertical and horizontal scroll wheels; vertical scroll wheel supports ratcheted and free-spinning scrolling
- Real mouse ;)

It's quite expensive at an MSRP of $99.99, but both it and it's cousins have been very well received by critics, and frankly, given it's feature set and backing from Logitech, I consider it well-worth it since you mentioned that price isn't a big issue for you.

Comment: If I use Bluetooth then I do not need the USB dongle, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.